# Xcode - Implement network error alerts into my app? Cant get it to work?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

I have downloaded and added apples reachability(.h+.m) files to my view bases project and not made any changes. I have also added the systemconfiguration.framework.

In my viewcontroller.h file I have added "@class reachability" just before "@interface", and I have also added "- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice;" just before "@end".

I have imported reachability.h into my viewcontroller.m file, here is the rest of it:

> // check for internet connection
>           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self           selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

```
    internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]             retain];
    [internetReachable startNotifier];

    // check if a pathway to a random host exists
    hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"]          retain];
    [hostReachable startNotifier];

    // now patiently wait for the notification

- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable            currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)

{
        case NotReachable:
{
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            self.internetActive = NO;       
            break;              
}
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
{
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            self.internetActive = YES;

            break;

}
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
{
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            self.internetActive = YES;

            break;
}
}
    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)     
{
        case NotReachable:
{
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            self.hostActive = NO;

            break;

}
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
{
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;

}
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
{
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
            self.hostActive = YES;

            break;              
}
}
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc:(BOOL)animated
{       
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I get 2 warnings:
-"Incorrect implementation of class 'TestViewController'" (which worked before I tried to do this)
-And also, "method definition for -'checkNetworkStatus:' not found"

The 2 errors are:
-"'checkNetworkStatus' undeclared"
-And "expected ';' before ':'"

Can anyone please help me?

EDIT:

.h file:

```
>#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Reachability;

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIView *landscape;
IBOutlet UIView *portrait;
IBOutlet UIView *portraitupsidedown;

IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView;
IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView2;
IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView3;
IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView4;

Reachability* internetReachable;
    Reachability* hostReachable;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *landscape;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *portrait;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIView *portraitupsidedown;

- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got one-too-many `}`s at the end of `checkNetworkStatus:`.  If your code was properly white-spaced then it would be much harder to make this kind of mistake.  By "properly white-spaced" I mean your code should look like this:

```
}
- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            self.internetActive = NO;       
            break;              
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            self.internetActive = YES;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            self.internetActive = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)     
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            self.hostActive = NO;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            self.hostActive = YES;
            break;    
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
            self.hostActive = YES;
            break;              
        }
    }
}
```

This formatting makes it trivial to find bracketing/nesting errors.  :)

Comment: Thanks for your help :) But I am still getting the exact same errors and warnings

Comment: Perhaps you copied my source code exactly as I put in my answer?  The mistake is still in the source code that I reformatted for you - remove the last `}` if you haven't.

Comment: How did you know? I removed the last }, but now I have got 3 errors and warnings the 2 same errors and warnings as before but also another new warning and error at the very end of the code. Expected declaration or statement at end of input and '@end' missing in implementation context.

Comment: Hey!  You're missing a `}` BEFORE `checkNetworkStatus:` and you had one too many after it (The one that used to come before it got moved behind it when you pasted).  I updated the code in my original answer so that if you paste it in for your checkNetworkStatus: then all should be well.

Comment: I am getting quite a lot of errors now :/ request for member 'internetActive' in something not a structure or union x3

Comment: request for member 'hostActive' in something not a structure or union x3

Comment: expected ';' before '{' token + expected declaration or statement at end of input + '@end' missing in implementation context

Comment: It's a good thing you posted your `.h` file - `internetActive` and `hostActive` aren't properties of `TestViewController` but you're trying to use them like they are.  Your problems have no moved far beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking I need to go back and learn objective-c better. Thanks for your help anyway.